# facebook and ssl page error

Tags: facebook, tomcat, ssl, load-balancing

I am working on porting over an app to ssl for facebook. I set up an elastic Load balancer to proxy ssl to a tomcat server. when I visit the URL it works in the browser but when I go to facebook it gives the error

Error

Error while loading page from $APPNAME
The URL https://secure.domain.com/$APPNAME/ did not respond.

but https://secure.domain.com/$APPNAME/ works in my browser. Theres no error logging I assume for facebook. Is there like a general rules why it would fail like facebook doesn't like the cert or something?

Comment: It might be caused by the new [Facebook Bug](http://developers.facebook.com/live_status)?